# Packing binary data in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, endianness

If I have unpacked binary data

```
1700885369 # translates to 'easy'
```

How can I get back to a byte array (most preferably without importing anything)? Like Python's [`struct.Struct(format).pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.Struct.pack):

```
>>> import struct
>>> s = struct.Struct('>1I') # a big-endian, two-byte, unsigned int
>>> s.pack(1700885369)
b'easy' # bytearray([101, 97, 115, 121])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a byte at a time from the value and put in an array:

```js
var value = 1700885369;
var arr = [];
while (value > 0) {
  arr.unshift(value % 256);
  value = Math.floor(value / 256);
}

// display value in StackOverflow snippet
document.write(arr);
```